Drv 8871 shield: is VM for the motor power supply?
I bought a simple board on AliExpress with DRV8871 soldered on top, the ILIM resistors and 2 capacitors for filtering.
There is a screw terminal block 4 positions on one side, labelled OUT1 and OUT2 and POWER+ and POWER-. This is clearly for motor outputs, motor power supply, and ground.
On the other side there is IN1 and IN2 for logic control, another ground (short circuited with the other one) and VM. Is VM the same of power+? If yes why do they put the same pin twice with different names?

refer to the datasheet for the board for description of the connections

In the drv8871 datasheet there is no mention to power+ and power-, only to vm and power ground, this is why I was wondering about the reason to introduce 2pins with different name in the shield

Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back to [edit] your question to address all comments. Do not add a comment for that, this is not a forum.

Please re-engineer the board and follow the traces to get a schematic. For example, you will find that power+ and VM are connected, or not. But because we have no access to the board, this is your task.

why do they put the same pin twice with different names? ... because that is what they chose to do
